# How to get Pixel coordinates from json file search with python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract coordinates from a json file. This file looks like this:
[image: annotations] In here you can find the json file [enter link description here](https://easyupload.io/xhhdml)

This 4 coordinates looks like this: `[[ 241, 1014, 1526, 1273 ], 1]`

Every block of coordinates is decorated with another number which correspond to the type of the block. As you can see, these 4 coordinates refer to type 1.

What I have to extract is all the coordinates that corrispond to the type **4** and the file they are belong to.
Moreover here is how keys and values looks like to me

[image: Keys and values]

Thanks

```html
import json
import re

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/DDM/annotations.json"
jsonFile = open(path)
annotation = json.load(jsonFile,)

print(annotation.keys())
print(annotation.values())


tags = [item for item in annotation if isinstance(item, str) and item.startswith(', 4')]
print(tags)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Please [edit] your question with your code as TEXT and not as image, it's better for us

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way

```html
import json
import re

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/DDM/annotations.json"



def findCoord(match, split):
  while((split[match-2] and split[match-1])!="["):
    match = match-1
  return match


file = open(path, "r")
annotation = file.read()


annSplit = annotation.split(']},')

for s in annSplit:
  if(s.find("], 4]")!=-1):
    endingCoord =s.find(", 4]")
    startingCoord = findCoord(endingCoord,s)
    print(s[startingCoord:endingCoord-1])
    endingPdf = s.find("annotation")
    startingPdf = endingPdf-25
    print(s[startingPdf:endingPdf-5])
    print("<------------------------------->")
```